# Добавить метки с разным оформлением из нескольких файлов JSON в файле JS

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть образец карты https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager
Как внутри одного файла JS сделать вызов 3-4 разных JSON файлов с метками, чтобы для каждого набора меток, можно было задать свой цвет, вид и тип меток и кластеров.
Спасибо!

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте несколько экземпляров ObjectManager, каждому задайте свои настройки. Соответственно, данные в каждый тоже можно передать свои.